# how to add some code in web.cofig file because this code needs again and again in code behind files

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an application in which when user login page load event check either there is a session for this user or not if there is no session user redirect to login.aspx file. But my web application has a lot of pages so instead of writing session code in every page load event I want to call it in page load event so I want to ask can I add this code in web.config file if yes then please help me how can I do this?
Thanks

```
 if (Session["LoginUserName"] != null)
 {
      string str;
      str = Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();
      Label1.Text = str;
 }
 else
 {
      Server.Transfer("Login_Form.aspx");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

make you all your Pages code inherit from a custom Class. Instead of the original class `System.Web.UI.Page`

Do it for all ASPX pages

```cs
public partial class MyPage : PageCommonBase
{
  ....
}
```

Make your custom class `PageCommonBase` and check for SessionUser `OnPreinit` Event

```cs
public class PageCommonBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnPreInit(e);

            if (
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession ||
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUserName"] == null
                )

            {
                   ......
            }
            else
                .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try it sir.